# Unexpected Identifier Error in JS Code

Tags: javascript, html, syntax-error

```
Error:expected an identifier and instead saw '<'
      expected')' and instead saw 'span'
      missing semicolon
      expected an identifier and instead saw ')'
      syntax error
```

Code:

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    // Your code here...
})(<span id="sbBalance">);
<span id="sbBalanceAmount">14</span> SB</span>;
```

Comment: well not sure how html mixed in JavaScript is supposed to work....

Comment: This is not jQuery either.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to do here, but parsing HTML within JavaScript (without a library for that purpose) isn't possible. Even with a library, your function isn't receiving any arguments passed to it.

The following snippet logs `bar` because your function accepts `foo` as an argument.

```js
(function(foo) {
  console.log(foo);
})('bar');
```